# Trigger href inside fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am trying to auto trigger the href inside my fancybox with this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#item_add_caps').click();
});
```

But this is not working. [Here is the site](http://www.goscrub.com/), the `href` is inside the a fancybox when you click the Paypal's Buy Now button, my goal is to have a default item ready in the cart.

Answer (score -1):

Just for triggering an href- this is the way to go:

```
$("#item_add_caps").click(function(){
      window.location.href = $("#item_add_caps").attr("href");
});
```

To do it on document ready, you can also use the shorthand:

```
$(function(){ // shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){ 
     window.location.href = $("#item_add_caps").attr("href"); 
}):
```

Which will only work if `#item_add_caps"` has a complete href, i.e. `http://www.example.com`

if `href` only contains a pathname such as `/example/pathame` - then you would use

`window.location.pathname`

Comment: did not work, this is what my `href` look like  

`<a id="item_add_caps" class="item_add" href="javascript:;"> Add to Cart </a>` 
and it is located inside the the fancybox.

Comment: It won't work anyway, since you href is just blank javascript:; --- There should be a function somewhere to tie it to. 
Or else, your original function would've worked, sort of. Or, otherwise, just using trigger(); would have worked.

Comment: Thus, you need to find out what function that link is really supposed to trigger -- and also, when you find that function, you do not need an href to trigger it, albeit, you can take all of the code mentioned here out, and just throw in the functions name like: `href='javascript:functionName;'`